# PyQt 4 - save all data in window to file on app close

Tags: python, pyqt

Is there a fast python way to save all data in all widgets to file before app is close?
And of course read it and restore after app is re-run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QWidget.saveGeometry` saves the geometry of an widget.
`QMainWindow.saveState` saves the window's toolbars and dockwidgets.
To save other things you can use pickle.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question [How to remember last geometry of PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869721/how-to-remember-last-geometry-of-pyqt-application) and completing [@Artur Gaspar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286655) answer, this is a full working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize

class myApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super( myApp, self ).__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings( 'My company', 'myApp' )

        # Initial window size/pos last saved. Use default values for first time
        windowScreenGeometry = self.settings.value( "windowScreenGeometry" )
        windowScreenState = self.settings.value( "windowScreenState" )

        if windowScreenGeometry:
            self.restoreGeometry( windowScreenGeometry )

        else:
            self.resize( 600, 400 )

        if windowScreenState:
            self.restoreState( windowScreenState )

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # Write window size and position to config file
        self.settings.setValue( "windowScreenGeometry", self.saveGeometry() )
        self.settings.setValue( "windowScreenState", self.saveState() )
        e.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    frame = myApp()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```