# Impossible to save the size and the position of my windows on Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qsettings

When I move or/and resize my windows on my screen anyway , I would like to keep this parameters for the next time that I will run my application, but impossible.

I open a new issue because I don't see in the pyqt5 section what I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869721/how-to-remember-last-geometry-of-pyqt-application/56739448#56739448)

I'm on Linux (Manjaro) using PyCharm with the lastest PyQT5, Python and QT5 on a kernel 5.1.18-1.

I have tried several things like this : https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/mainwindows/application/application.py#L197-L207

I have not used the QDesktopWidget class : it seems to be depreciated : [QDesktopWidget class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html)

I'm on Linux (Manjaro) using PyCharm with the lastest PyQT5, Python and QT5 on a kernel 5.1.18-1.

```
#check if the hidden project folder is created by default, if not it is created
HOME_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~")
USER_PATH = os.path.join(HOME_PATH, ".mx5000")
if not os.path.exists(USER_PATH):
    os.mkdir(USER_PATH)
#configFolder = os.path.join(QDir.homePath(), ".mx5000")
#configFile = os.path.join(QDir.homePath(), ".mx5000/config.conf")
#configLog = os.path.join(QDir.homePath(), ".mx5000/logfile")

config_path = os.path.join(USER_PATH, "config.ini")
#settings = QSettings()
# config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# config['DEFAULT'] = {'path_keyboard': "/dev/hiddev0",
#                      'keyboard_name': "Whatever",
#                      'server_type':    "self.ui.rdbimap.setChecked(True)",
#                      'server_adress': "self.ui.lneserveradress.setText(imap.yourserver.com)",
#                      'username': 'username',
#                      'password': "cnffjbep",
#                      'time_to_check': '10',
#                      'keyboard_beep': '1',
#                      'play_sound': '1',
#                      'sound_directory': "/home/user/.mx5000/notify.ogg"}
#if not os.path.isfile("config"):
    #os.mkdir(USER_PATH)
# with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
      config.write(configfile)


class Mx5000(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mx5000, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setupUi()
    self.connectActions()
    self.dirty = False
    self.loadSettings()
    # self.default_size = QSize(615, 800)
    # self.default_position = QPoint(20, 20)
    # self.ui.lneserveradress.setText('imap.yourserver.com')
    # settings = QSettings()
    # pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
    # size = settings.value("size", QSize(615, 800))
    # self.resize(size)
    # self.move(pos)

       #===============================================================================
...

def closeEvent(self, event):
    if self.okToContinue():
        # settings = QSettings()
        # pass
        self.writeSettings()
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

#====================================================================================================================

def loadSettings(self):
    settings = QSettings('Exemple app', 'MX5000')
    pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
    size = settings.value("size", QSize(615, 800))
    self.resize(size)
    self.move(pos)

def writeSettings(self):
    settings = QSettings('Exemple app', 'MX5000')
    settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
    settings.setValue("size", self.size())
    #====================================================
    # settings.setValue("size", QSize(615, 800).tosize())
    # settings.setValue("pos", QPoint(200, 200).toPoint())
    #====================================================

    settings.sync()

#===================================================================================================================

def okToContinue(self):

    if self.dirty is True:
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, self.tr("MX 5000", "Did you want to close the application ?"),
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Cancel:
            return False
        elif reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.Mx5000.close()
            self.application.quit()
            self.writeSettings()
            return True
```

The entire files (Python and ui) are available if it is not clear for a while here :
[python file](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZirga7Z1jNj4VPM6rLKHsvpStkPmfOuGfsk)

and

[ui file](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZKcga7Z0emsFtu94xmUbeNDOwaKqLSq4fm7)

By Advance Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit strange, each method / function must have a specific task, in the case of okToContinue() method I guess you should only verify if the user accepts the closing or not of the window if a flag was activated otherwise it is considered that I accept the close, it is not necessary to add more code.

Considering the above the solution is:

```py
class Mx5000(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mx5000, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self.dirty = False
        self.loadSettings()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.ui = Ui_MX5000()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.okToContinue():
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def loadSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("Exemple app", "MX5000")
        pos = settings.value("pos", QtCore.QPoint(200, 200))
        size = settings.value("size", QtCore.QSize(615, 800))
        self.resize(size)
        self.move(pos)

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("Exemple app", "MX5000")
        settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
        settings.setValue("size", self.size())

    def okToContinue(self):
        if self.dirty:
            reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
                self,
                self.tr("MX 5000", "Did you want to close the application ?"),
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes
                | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No
                | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
            )
            return reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eyllanesc for trying to help me. Yes, it is because I've tried the both methods (in Python and in QT) and it has been enough confusing for me and block me too since a long time). It is time for me to resolve this issue. You have well understood the purpose of this method. I've modified my code and I got the same result. I've done the same thing on another app which have less code and I'm not able to keep the change made. I not have MB displaying.If you want the code of this other application (it is so minimal and less confusing, tell me). Another thing that I don't understand why.

Comment: Another thing that I don't understand why. Before populate this functions, my app was centred on my screen, since she is on the left when I run it. Why ? Did you have an idea about this strange behaviour ?

Comment: @olielvewen Without an MRE it is impossible to help you, if you have a repo in GH your project I could do a PR with the implementation.

Comment: I have  a GH repo but not for that project. I'm going to do all modifications and tell you were you could find it. I'll put too the other gui more simple to understand. Let me do that and I'll you more. Thanks eyllanesc.

Comment: I've done modifications and you can find the code in folders MX5000 and estabilize [here](https://github.com/olielvewen/Mockups.git). Use the magic command `git clone https://github.com/olielvewen/Mockups.git` but you know it, that 's sure.

Comment: @olielvewen For me it works correctly, you could explain the problem in detail, but do not do it here anymore but in the PR that I have done to you

Comment: Okay I've seen. Just for info I'm using Python 3.7.3, Qt5.12.3 PyQt5.12.2 (use About-QDvGrab)